# Can HID Input/Feature reports have side-effects for the device?

Tags: embedded, usb, hid

To talk to an embedded device. I'm [ab]using the USB HID protocol, as seems to be common.

Due to limitations of the device stack (it's a Freescale Kinetis KL26 with their SDK) it supports only Output and GetFeature on EP0, and Interrupt Input on EP1. I'm mostly using EP0 for I/O.

What's prompted my question is the discovery that a Linux host downloads all Feature Reports at enumeration time (which is a problem, because on my device, they have side-effects). Is there any reliable way to stop the host getting reports except when an application explicitly requests them? [I've tried flagging all reports as "Volatile" but it doesn't take the hint.]

More generally: Does HID impose any rules to say that  getting Feature or Input Reports must be idempotent or free from side-effects (kinda analogous to REST)? I can't find any such rule in the HID class specification, but maybe it's implicit.

Thanks

Comment: My general experience with USB and enumeration (chapter 9 stuff) is that each OS does it differently, in different orders, and makes different decisions as to what to do to your USB device and probably changes over versions.    Relying on this behavior is asking for trouble.  You ought to have a SET Feature/Report enable your side effect functionality so random polling of the reports prior to setup doesn't trigger anything.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I think I can make the initial polling harmless; in fact my "side-effects" are not dramatic, it just consumes the data that I intended to read. It would be a problem if the OS were to continue spontaneously getting reports concurrently with my application.